# When i click a button i need to click twice how can i fix this

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am doing login using firebase but when I click the login button nothing happens unless I click it again. How can I fix this? I have left out all the firebase related code. (it goes on for quite a bit). if u need it I am happy to upload it.
there is stuff before the on state changed but I haven't uploaded it (i am happy to if you need it though).

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    AfterAuth() 
  }

});
        // [END authwithemail]


    }
}


    function AfterAuth (argument) {
        console.log("hered")
        document.getElementById("PopUpDivLogin").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("ShowAfterLogin").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("ShowAfterLoginButton").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("ShowBeforeLogIn").style.display="none";

document.getElementById("ButtonLogContainer").style.display="none";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="SignInInuptBoxes">
    <div id="SignLogPopup">Sign In</div>
    <input class="InputLogin" id="EmailLogin" placeholder="Email...">
    <br>
<input type="password"class="InputLogin" id="PasswordLogIn" placeholder="Password...">
<br>
<button class="SignLogPopUp" onclick="SignInForProgram()">Sign In</button>
</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks, Hamish

Comment: Did you find a solution on your own or do you still need help with this?

Comment: i think i found a solution. thanks.